# Configure my wireless printer in ubuntu

Tags: printing

Newbie, but I have a dual boot win10/ubuntu system and on the linux side I need to be able to print to my epson wf3530. The printer shows up under printers, but the location is blank. The connection line shows this:

SON0B26D2.local:631/Epson_IPP_Printer

And the driver shows as the correct driver. From within linux how do I find the physical address of the printer?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check directly in the printer's settings?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: That's up to you and the printer's user's manual, etc. I assume you already installed it in Windows with the help of some software/drivers for Windows. How to configure it in Ubuntu is on-topic in this site but checking its properties, something likely to be done in same of the printer's menus, isn't. Your question is specifically about "find the physical address of the printer" (IP address??) and that certainly is easier to find in the printer settings.

Comment: If your Ubuntu system and the printer already see each other, then why do you need the "physical address?" (whatever that is). Usually the "location" field is for a human label (upstairs, The Green One, break room, etc.)  Your Ubuntu system seems likely to connect to the printer automagically without much effort by you.

Comment: I assumed I needed it because I can't print; I get the error Unable to locate SON0B26D2.local:631/Epson_IPP_Printer.